# Pass foreign key in Golang gin

Tags: go, go-gorm, go-gin

Here is my code snippet I'm trying to pass `language_id` along with book create call somehow I'm getting an error

```
func Create(c *gin.Context) {
    dbb := c.MustGet("db").(*gorm.DB)
    book := Models.BookModel{
        Title:  c.PostForm("title"),
        Author: c.PostForm("author"),
        LanguageID: c.PostForm("language_id"),
    }

    dbb.Save(&book)
    c.JSON(http.StatusCreated, gin.H{"status": http.StatusCreated, "message": "Book created successfully!", "bookId": book.ID})
}
```

error is 
`Cannot use 'c.PostForm("language_id")' (type string) as type int`
any help that would be great thanks!

Comment: Please add the error too

Comment: Err is here. c.PostForm only accepts a string. `LanguageID: c.PostForm("language_id"),`
```Cannot use 'c.PostForm("language_id")' (type string) as type int ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `LanguageID` is an int type and you wanna pass a string value to it, you should parse it to int like:

```
func Create(c *gin.Context) {
dbb := c.MustGet("db").(*gorm.DB)

languageID, err := strconv.Atoi(c.PostForm("language_id"))
 if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    return
}

book := Models.BookModel{
    Title:  c.PostForm("title"),
    Author: c.PostForm("author"),
    LanguageID: languageID,
}

dbb.Save(&book)
c.JSON(http.StatusCreated, gin.H{"status": http.StatusCreated, "message": "Book created successfully!", "bookId": book.ID})
}
```

Comment: Thanks! also can you help me like how to apply validation rules in the model it self?

Comment: Your welcome, for validation in struct level you can use this package [go-playground/validator](https://github.com/go-playground/validator) it's well documented and easy to use, also it's default validator for the gin web framework

Comment: how to add a validator here in my create method here
```
func CreateLanguage(c *gin.Context)  {
 dbb := c.MustGet("db").(*gorm.DB)
 language := Models.Language{
  Name: c.PostForm("name"),
 }
        validate = validator.New()
 dbb.Save(&language)
 c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{"status": http.StatusOK, "data": "Language Created.", "language": language.ID})
}
```